# Batch to parse lines containing a specific string from an input file

Tags: batch-file

Edit: yes, this has to be done in batch.

I need to be able to read an input file, and parse out certain sections only of lines that contain a specific string, then write that to an output file. For example:

input =

```
i_NumberOfPersonInTheDataBase=1
i_NumberOfPersonInTheDataBase < 50 AdjTotal=801
MATCH IdentificationResult id=Olivier Score=11419 (NOT_DEFINED-cfv )
02-11-11-07-00 TAG_CAPTURE Badge:CAPTURE - Candidate Found :Olivier
i_NumberOfPersonInTheDataBase=1
i_NumberOfPersonInTheDataBase < 50 AdjTotal=801
MATCH IdentificationResult id=Martin Score=1008 (NOT_DEFINED-cfv )
02-11-11-08-15 TAG_CAPTURE Badge:CAPTURE - Candidate Found :Martin
```

in lines that contain the string "IdentificationResult", I need to return the strings that contain the id and Score.

expected output =

```
id=Olivier Score=11419
id=Martin Score=1008
```

This is what I have so far:

```
@setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

:: Path of input and output files
set INPUTFILE=DemoFingerOtf-2.log
set OUTPUTFILE=logOutput.txt

:: Clear out the output file
@echo on > %OUTPUTFILE%

:: Read %INPUTFILE% and loop through each line
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%INPUTFILE%) do (
    SET my_line=%%A
    SET my_line=!my_line:IdentificationResult=!
    if not !my_line!==%%A (
     call :parse_it
  )   
)

:parse_it
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=~" %%1 in ('%my_line: =~%') do (
    echo %%3 %%4>> %OUTPUTFILE%
)
```

The problem I have right now is that when I run this script, I get a **') was unexpected at this time** error. When I remove the parentheses from the input, I get my expected results. I've tried including a line like the following to remove the parentheses:

```
:: Read %INPUTFILE% and loop through each line
for /F "tokens=* delims=" %%A in (%INPUTFILE%) do (
    SET my_line=%%A
    SET my_line=!my_line:IdentificationResult=!
    if not !my_line!==%%A (
     SET new_line=%my_line:~0,-18%
     call :parse_it
  )   
)

:parse_it
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=~" %%1 in ('%new_line: =~%') do (
    echo %%3 %%4>> %OUTPUTFILE%
)
```

I know that in the lines I want, the section with parentheses will always be exactly 18 characters, so I trim them from the end. However, when I do that, for some reason I get the following as my output:

wrong output:

```
id=Olivier Score=11419
id=Olivier Score=11419
id=Olivier Score=11419
```

So, I'm getting only the data from the first line that I want to parse, and I'm getting it three times (even though there are only two lines in my input that meet my criteria). Why am I getting this data multiple times instead of the correct data? Additionally, is there a better way around the **') was unexpected at this time** error that I was getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit modificated without trailing space. Without "ScoreAdjustment" and work with "John Smith" :)

```
echo off

:: Path of input and output files
set INPUTFILE=DemoFingerOtf-2.log
set OUTPUTFILE=logOutput.txt


setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2,3 delims=^=^(" %%a in ('type "%INPUTFILE%" ^| find /i "IdentificationResult"') do (
                                                                   set $line=Id=%%a=%%b
                                                                   set $line=!$line:ScoreAdjustment=!
                                                                   set $line=!$line:~0,-1!
                                                                   echo !$line!>>%OUTPUTFILE%)

Endlocal
```

Comment: this is a lot simpler than what I was doing, but I don't fully understand what is going on here. specifically, what controls what values are stored in %%a and %%b?

Comment: just use `"tokens=2,3 delims==("`, no need for carets. And your output has a trailing space in every line.

Comment: %%a (tokens 2) take the value between the "=" (delims ^=) delimiter [Olivier Score]and the %%b (tokens 3) take the value before the ")" (delims ^)) [11419] That's why i put the "Id=" before %%a and = after, to get the correct Output :)

Comment: yea, before the _opening_ parenthesis including one space!

Comment: not for me :) but you can't call this `correct output`. Space is one space to much :)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This works for most of my input, but some input lines have lines like `id=Olivier Score=11419 ScoreAdjustment=801`, so the output has an extra "ScoreAdjustment" at the end, which I don't want. Is there a solution that works for that too?

Answer (score 1):

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('^<file find "IdentificationResult"') do call:DOit "%%~a"
goto:Eof

:doit
setlocal
set "string=%~1"
set "STring=%string:*IdentificationResult=%"
for /f "Tokens=1,2" %%b in ("%string%") do echo(%%b %%c
exit /b
```

Comment: well this doesn't answer my question, but this solution works perfectly. thanks!

Comment: actually, I encountered a problem. Some of the data has a space in the "id" field, so my output is `id=John Smith` instead of `id=John Smith Score=1337`. Is there a solution that accounts for this?

Comment: See the new Edit of my code. It work now for all your case :)

Comment: IT would be better to use Regex here :) `grep` or `sed` or a hybrid `batch/basic` script like [repl.bat](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/2098699).

Comment: @sachadee to make life easier and more enjoyable.

Comment: For sure @Endoro life will be so much easier for our friend preppypoof with grep, sed or hybrid batch/basic or batch/c. Why make simple when we can complicate....

Answer (score 1):

The easy way:

```
    if not !my_line!==%%A (
     ECHO !my_line:~7,-19!>> %OUTPUTFILE%
    )
```

A few issues with your code, but I applaud your effort to solve the problem.

Batch doesn't stop at a label - they're just markers, so it charges straight through, hence you'd need a

```
goto :eof
```

before any suboutine label.

You can't use numerics as metavariables, so in `parse_it` you'd need a letter, not `1`. You can also use space as a `delims` character - but it must be specified as the last delimiter (ie. just before the closing <kbd>"</kbd>

So `parse_it` could be reduced (if it was required) to

```
for /F "tokens=1* delims= " %%q in ("%new_line%") do (
    echo %%r>> %OUTPUTFILE%
)
```

But - overall, bravo for the attempt!

Comment: thank you for actually answering my question instead of giving me a different solution. I am going to use one of the other solutions instead because my input file is quite large and they are a lot faster, but I appreciate that you explained some of my mistakes.

Answer (score -1):

You dont say what language you want. so can you do something like:

```
grep IdentificationResult file | awk '{ print $3, $4}' > output.file
```

Comment: The question is tagged as `batch-file` and his code is Windows batch, so presumably he wants it in Windows batch language.

Comment: yes, it has to be done in batch. i'll edit that in the main post.

Comment: `grep` and `awk` are available for the Windows cmd command shell.

Comment: as far as I know, grep isn't available by default in Windows and the end user may not have access to that.